# Regex Adding Trailing zero's

Tags: regex, replace, pentaho

I am attempting to pad zeros to a series of numbers in transforming data.

Basically I have something like this:

```
1234
2345
3456
4567
```

And What I want to transform to is

```
12340000
23450000
34560000
45670000
```

What I have tried so far is

```
regex: ^(.+)$
replace: $1/0000  => 1234/0000
replace: $10000   => NOTHING
replace: $1\0000  => 1234\0000
```

Would be great if someone can help me out.

Comment: What is the language / engine?

Comment: I am using a transforming tool call Pentaho, which use I believe java regex standard.

Comment: Are regex replacements really easier than just multiplying numbers by 10000?  Also ... Pentaho?  The [Hello World example page on their wiki](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/03.+Hello+World+Example) talks about "the goal for your first transformation".  I can't be the only one scared of this language.

Comment: @ghoti this is not my first transformation, and pentaho is not that hard, if you have millions of records in CSV and need then to be imported into a database, it's one of the best tool to use. But the idea of multiplying by 10000 might be the easiest solution and thank you for that pointer.

Comment: I just attempted regex: `$`, and replace with `0000`. It works, but it is so error prone that I am not sure if I feel comfortable using it. I still think ghoti's answer by multiplying 10K is probably the best idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have these fields as numbers, @ghoti solution of multiplying them by 10000 sounds the best.
But if you have them as strings I really dont know what behavior you would like for a string with less or more than 4 chars ex. "123" or "98765" (as you didn't define it on your question).

1- If you want to turn it into "1230000"/"987650000" (just concat 4 zeros) then you can use a Calculator step, creating a temporary constant field "0000" than creating a field being the sum of your original field and this temp field;

2- If you want to turn it into "12300000"/"98765000" (both 8 chars) then you can use a String Operations step choosing Padding = right, Pad char = 0 and Pad Length = 9 (don't ask me why 9 and not 8).

Both steps are really usefull for string operations, hope they help you.

Comment: I didn't find any of the solution here as a good solution, because they are all somewhat hack'ish approach on how to do a regular expression search and replace, and because how regex replacement string is formulated, it is impossible for me to actually get it done with regex. Therefore I think your solution of multiple by 10000 ended up to be the simplest work around, so I am accepting this answer as a work around.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Notepad++

```
regex: ^(.+)$
replace: \1\20000
```

I tried it with $1$20000 and it did not work :(

Another method that worked was the following

```
regex: ^(.+)$
replace: $1z0000
regex: ^(.+)z(0000)$
replace: $1$2
```

This worked too

```
regex: ^(.+)$
replace: $1(0000)
```

Comment: I attempted the replace `$1(0000)` also, and that returned me `1234(0000)`, the transform tools allows me only a single pass transformation, so I need to somehow do it correctly the first time around.

Answer (score 0):

How about the regex `(?<=^\d+)$` and the simple replacement `0000`? That won't match the existing numbers, it just ensures they are there before the zero-width match position at the end of the line.

Comment: If you have no match, then you can't replace. I tested your example. It can't find anything, therefore replace never took place.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you should use a pad function e.g. one of the ones in the modified javascript step, rather than any kind of regex.